# Pass params while Node app is running

Tags: node.js, shell, terminal, cron, system-calls

Is there way to pass and get parameters to a running node app? Looking for something like signals but with custom params.

```
process.on('runX', function (params) {
  console.log('RunX called. Params:' + params);
});

$ passParams nodeAppPID runX param1 param2
```

The final problem which I try to solve is to pass params into the app by cron.

Comment: Yes, give your application a little REST API running on localhost. NodeJS is good at this. If you want something lower-level, try sockets.

Comment: @byxor yes, I was thinking about Rest API. But it seems overkill, I don't need to have access outside of machine where the app is running. Just need to pass little chunk of data to the app by cron.

Comment: You can use `process.stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments there're two solutions:

1. use [process.stdin](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin). But seems there're other issues with stream writing.
2. make local server and call it via curl.

Utility class for the second solution:

```
class RemoteControl {

    constructor(port) {

        this.prefix = '/remote/';
        this.handlers = [];
        this.initServer(port);
    }

    initServer(port) {
        const http = require('http');
        const self = this;

        const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            self.handleRequest(req.url);
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.end('');
        });

        server.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`RemoteControl running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
        });

        this.addCall('ping', function () {
            console.log('Remote ping ok');
        });
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param url {String}
     */
    handleRequest(url) {

        let handlerFound = false;

        for (let index in this.handlers) {
            let handler = this.handlers[index];
            if (url === handler.name) {
                console.log('handler called for ' + url);
                handlerFound = true;
                handler.handler();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!handlerFound) console.log('handler not found for ' + url);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param callName {String}
     * @param handler {Function}
     */
    addCall(callName, handler) {
        this.handlers.push(new Handler(this.prefix + callName, handler));
    }
}

class Handler {
    /**
     * @param name {String}
     * @param handler {Function}
     */
    constructor(name, handler) {
        this.name = name;
        this.handler = handler;
    }
}

module.exports = RemoteControl;
```

Client code usage:

```
const remoteControl = new RemoteControl(6666)
remoteControl.addCall('hello', function(){
  //handle hello call
});
```

Cron job:

```
* * * * * curl http://localhost:6666/remote/hello
```